# How to use find and prename to reformat directory names recursively?

Tags: shell, find, rename

I am trying to find all directories that start with a year in brackets, such as this:

```
[1990] Nature Documentary
```

and then rename them removing brackets and inserting a dash in between.

```
1990 - Nature Documentary
```

The `find` command below seems to find the results, however I could not prefix the pattern with `^` to mark start of directory name otherwise its not returning hits.

I am pretty sure I need to use `-exec` or `-execdir`, but I am not sure how to store the found pattern and manipulate it.

```
find . -type d -name '\[[[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]]] *'
```

Comment: That is a glob, not regex. And you don't need to anchor it to the beginning because `-name` primary doesn't evaluate to true if the match is partial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `[p]rename`:

```
-depth -exec prename -n 's/\[(\d{4})]([^\/]+)$/$1 -$2/' {} +
```

<sup>Drop `-n` if the output looks good.</sup>

Without it, you'd need a shell script with several hardly intelligible parameter expansions there:

```
-depth -exec sh -c '
for dp; do
  yr=${dp##*/[} yr=${yr%%]*}
  echo mv "$dp" "${dp%/*}/$yr -${dp##*/\[????]}"
done' sh {} +
```

<sup>Remove `echo` to apply changes.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can use the rename command

```
find . -type d -name '\[[[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]]\] *'| rename -n 's/(\[\d{4}\]) ([\w,\s]+)+$/$1 - $2/'
```

**Note**: The effect will not take place until you delete the `-n` option.